# Kendo UI with asp.net

Tags: asp.net, kendo-ui

How can I use Kendo UI with asp.net web application?

Because when I try to create an asp.net application and added kendo.mvc.dll in my bin folder. Now I've added:

```
<%= Html.Kendo().Calendar().Name("calendar")  %>
```

in my default.aspx page. Now it is saying "The name HTML does not exist in the current context".

What is the issue in that?

Comment: `kendo.mvc.dll` is for asp.net-MVC only. Try to download the correct product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use Kendo for MVC when your web application is not MVC.

You need to use Kendo UI WEB

http://www.kendoui.com/download.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you follow these simple steps from the documentation?

http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/introduction#manually-add-kendo-ui-to-aspnet-mvc-applications

In particular I'm referring to the step 7 where you must add the namespece in your `web.config`:

```
 <namespaces>
     <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
     <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
     <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
     <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
     <add namespace="System.Linq" />
     <add namespace="System.Collections.Generic" />
     <add namespace="Kendo.Mvc.UI" />
 </namespaces>
```

Comment: I've already added and getting below Error The type or namespace name 'Html' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web.Mvc' (are you missing an assembly reference?) KendoPract\web.config.   Note: I'm not working with MVC application.  Is it required?

Comment: You are using an MVC syntax so... yes it's necessary for what you have wrote in your code.